# Why SHAP Values are not Adding up to Predicted Probability?

Tags: r, xgboost, r-caret, xgbclassifier

I was wondering if my following setup is correct to generate SHAP values from a model using CARET's xgbDART method. The problem in this particular case is that SHAP values `rowSums()` doesnt add up to the predicted score. Any direction would be very helpful. Here is my setup:

```
#model scores
set.seed(200)
pred_mod<- predict(xgb_05_v6$finalModel, 
                   newdata= as.matrix(X1),
                   ntreelimit = param_dart$nrounds, 
                   objective = "binary:logistic",
                   outputmargin = TRUE
                   ) 

#SHAP values
set.seed(200)
SHAP_contribution<- predict(xgb_05_v6$finalModel, 
                    newdata= as.matrix(X1),
                    ntreelimit = param_dart$nrounds, 
                    objective = "binary:logistic",
                    approxcontrib = FALSE,
                    predcontrib = TRUE

)
```